# Node-Cron not installing on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am using Node js for a personal project but I keep getting the same problem when installing node-cron.
When deploying on Heroku, it keeps giving me the same error message seen below but does not occur when installing it locally.

I tried finding others with similar problems online but nothing seems to pop up. Would be much appreciated if someone could find a solution!

```
> node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall /tmp/build_13203812b696ff71f401fd657fdd6fdd/node_modules/node-cron
remote:        > opencollective-postinstall
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: opencollective-postinstall: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall: `opencollective-postinstall`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: have you tried it with sudo su ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `|| exit 0` at the end of the `postinstall` script in `package.json` to make sure this never stops the npm install process.

Answer (score 0):

Actually issue is with the opencollective and since node-cron uses this, issue comes.

Install opencollective-postinstall npm package and add postinstall script in your package.json:

```
"postinstall": "opencollective-postinstall || exit 0"
```

Using `exit 0` is to prevent the process from stopping even if the script fails.

https://github.com/mattezell/ngx-infinite-scroll/commit/fc7165bd099145321235948723ee6e644ded65a8